# Movement & starting point of s1->top in the following functions, push, display & pop

Tags: c, stack

Can someone help me understand whats happening in the following functions? Specifically the use of s1->top? And what is the movement of s1->top in the functions push &pop & display? Because if in function push, s1->top moves to the right whenever a number is pushed? then why in the display function, it says s1->top is first in the traversing, while in push s1->top is n the right, while in printing the values, we need to firstly be in the left and then traverse..why?

```
typedef struct node* Nodeptr;
typedef char dataitem;

typedef struct node{
dataitem data;
Nodeptr next;
}Node;

typedef struct{
int count;
Nodeptr top;
}Stack_Head;

typedef Stack_Head* Stack;

Stack createStack() {
  Stack s1;
  s1 = (Stack) malloc(sizeof(Stack_Head));
  s1 - > count = 0;
  s1 - > top = NULL;
  return s1;
}

Nodeptr createNode(dataitem item) {
  Nodeptr temp;
  temp = (Nodeptr) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  temp - > data = item;
  temp - > next = NULL;
  return temp;
}

void push(Stack s1, dataitem item) {
  Nodeptr temp = createNode(item);
  temp - > next = s1 - > top;
  s1 - > top = temp;
  s1 - > count++;
}

void display(Stack s1) {
  Nodeptr ptr = s1 - > top;
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    printf("%d", ptr - > data);
    ptr = ptr - > next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void pop(Stack s1) {
    Nodeptr temp;
    if (isEmpty(s1))
      printf("List is Empty");
    else {
      temp = s1 - > top;
      s1 - > top = temp - > next;
      temp - > next = NULL;
      free(temp);
      s1 - > count;
    }

    int isEmpty(Stack s1) {
      return s1 - > top == NULL;
    }
```

Comment: show us the definition of Stack, Stack_head and all other other structs

Comment: for a sec, ill edit

Comment: edit done Sir @Sush

Answer (score 0):

First off, let's fix a bug - in function `display()`, I assume the line :

```
while (ptr1 = NULL) {
```

should really be :

```
while (ptr != NULL) {
```

In your question, you refer to "left" and "right", but as the variable "top" implies, it's easier visualising a vertical stack.

For example, imagine a stack of dinner plates.  New plates are always "push"ed onto the top, and on demand they are also "popped" from the top.

So as you can see, this sort of stack is called a Last-In-First-Out (or LIFO) stack, and this is what your code is implementing.

The `s1->top` variable is a pointer to the top of the stack - ie. the last node added, which will also be the first to be removed.  Each node also has a pointer to the `next` node "under" it.   NULL is used to indicate "no more nodes", both for `s1->top`, and the `node->next` pointers.

So in `push()`, two things must happen for consistency :

1. The new arrival's `->next` pointer must be set to the current
   "top" of the stack (so the existing top is "under" the new arrival),
   and
2. The new arrival must be set as the new "top".

Note that the order of operations here is important - if (2) was performed before (1), then you could end up with the new arrival's "->next" pointer pointing to itself !

`pop()` performs basically those operations in reverse, and `display()` simply runs down all the elements in the stack (notice that `display()` does NOT alter the value of `s1->top` ).

Comment: i even didnt think about , he doesnt know what is stack, if he uses it

Comment: so are you saying that in display, it runs down from s1->top which is the top then going down?? .. is it the work of traversing which is from top going down? i learned in school it is from left to right

Comment: s1->top is the newest inserted element, then display is starting of with it while its the last element, why?

Comment: @PatrickEsguerra  Traversing "top going down" or "left to right" is ONLY our mental picture; there is no difference to the program, no right-or-wrong answer.  I could have written the answer using "left-most" instead of "top", and "to the right" instead of "under", and it would all have been the same.  However, stacks are most commonly VISUALISED as vertical (eg. look at "stack abstract data type" in wikipedia).   I don't understand "while its the last element" in your second post.

Comment: No reason it shouldn't.  It makes sense to start at the display at the next element to be "popped".  Just as important, starting anywhere else would require either a second pointer alongside "s1->top", or some pre-processing to find the alternative start-point - no good reason for either.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know wahts your problem, 
after fixing some missclicks in your code like
`while(ptr1 = NULL)` to `while(ptr != NULL)`,
and `printf("%f")` - to `"%c"`

for this code

```
int main() {    
        Stack a = createStack();    
        push(a, 'a');
        push(a, 'b');
        push(a, 'c');
        push(a, 'd');
        push(a, 'e');    
        display(a);

        return 0;
}
```

i got correct output with

```
//edcba
```